# How to identify invalid (corrupted) values stored in Oracle DATE columns

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle10g

Oracle 10.2.0.5

What is the easiest way to identify rows in a table that have "invalid" values in DATE columns. By "invalid" here what I mean is a binary representation that violates Oracle rules for date values.

I recently had an issue with an invalid date stored in a column.

I was able to use a query predicate to find a particular problematic row:

```
  WHERE TO_CHAR(date_expr,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') = '00000000000000'
```

In the case I had, the century byte was invalid...

```
 select dump(h.bid_close_date) from mytable h where h.id = 54321

 Typ=12 Len=7: 220,111,11,2,1,1,1
```

The century byte should be 100 + two digit century. In this case, there was an extra 100 added, as if the century value was "120", making the year "12011".  (The only way I know to get invalid DATE values into the database is using OCI, using native 7-byte DATE representation.)

In this case, the TO_CHAR function returned an identifiable string, which I could use for identifying the wonky DATE value.

My question: is there an more general or easier approach (preferably using a SQL SELECT statement) to identify rows with "invalid" values in DATE columns.

Comment: Can you select all dates not within a specified valid range?

Comment: There *was* a bug in earlier versions of Oracle (9.x?) that allowed divide-by-zero of INTERVAL values to go undetected and produced invalid values.

Comment: How did you manage to get them into the database in the first place?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It's not entirely clear how these corrupted date values were inserted... the developers didn't know where in the software it could have happened. I believe the OCI (Oracle Call Interface) allows for passing in Oracle binary representation (7 bytes, cc+100, yy+100, mm, dd, hh+1, mi+1, ss+1) and that using this feature "bypasses" the checks that Oracle would normally perform on DATE values. (This puts the onus on the software to ensure that the values provided to Oracle are valid.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This identifies invalid months

```
SELECT rowid,
       pk_column,
       DUMP(date_column, 1010) AS dump1
FROM   table
WHERE  TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(DUMP(date_column, 1010), INSTR(DUMP( date_column, 1010),
                                              ',', 1, 2
                                                     ) + 1,
                                  INSTR(DUMP(date_column, 1010), ',', 1, 3) - (
                                  INSTR(DUMP( date_column, 1010), ',', 1, 2) + 1
                                  ))) = 0;
```

Update using the same where clause, I found the  month number was zero in these cases.

Comment: Can a similar pattern be used to identify invalid "century" and "year" values, in a Oracle internal 7-byte representation   100+cc, 100+yy, mm, dd, ... ? (I considered using `DUMP`, but parsing the string and validating the components (in the context of SQL query) seemed a bit daunting. What I wanted was a simple predicate that would test/validate values in a DATE column, something along the lines of  `WHERE date_col IS any_invalid_value`  ... that's what I couldn't find

Comment: You can't do that simple query because ANY_INVALID_VALUE breaks the conversion from bytes in the row to the date type in the program. The Internal and External representation of Oracle data gets in the way here. Internally SQL is calling something like OCIDateCheck(). I've blogged about it here [https://sites.google.com/site/fgordonie/blog/oracle/datatypes_and_errors]. You're stuck with the query above changing the INSTR to extract the century parts. Look at this [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28427/pc_15ody.htm#i33925] to show you how Oracle handles it INTERNALLY.

Comment: thanks for the information. I do have an understanding of the Oracle internals. And as I indicated, using `DUMP` was my first inclination. but I settled on using a query with the condition shown in my answer `WHERE TO_CHAR(date_col,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') = '000000000000'`. That identifies the rows that have corrupted/invalid values in date_col. Note that I just want to *identify* the rows. I can use DUMP to investigate the actual values that are stored. But the question I was asking was about the simplest predicate to reliably find all of rows with corrupted `date_col` values.

Comment: The only way I know to be completely sure is to write an OCI program which I've had to do only once in the last 30 years I've worked with Oracle. I don't think it can be done from SQL as its already being converted to some sort of "External" representation even when using TO_CHAR, in effect it's too late by the time you get to SQL.

Comment: i think that's the probably the answer... use OCI to pull back the internal representation. and perform the required checks. If we want to do the validation using SQL, we can use DUMP to get us a view of the internals. As you demonstrated, TO_CHAR does not return all zeros for all corrupted/invalid DATE values; we get all zeros only in some special cases. Sadly, Oracle doesn't provide a function that validates internal DATE representation as a simple boolean condition (to return a simple true/false).

Answer (score 6):

This is a pretty unusual scenario (although I have come across something similar once before).  The more common problem is finding invalid dates which are held as strings in a date column.  You could adapt the solution for that to your situation, by building your own date validator.

Something like this:

```
create or replace function is_a_date 
    ( p_date in date )
    return varchar2
is
    d date;
begin
    d := to_date(to_char(p_date,  'SYYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),  'SYYYYMMDDHH24MISS') ;
    if d != p_date then
        return 'not a proper date';
    else
        return 'good date';
    end if;
exception
    when others  then
        return 'not a date';
end;
/
```

This converts a date into a string and back again.  It catches exceptions thrown by date casting.   If the end product is not the same as the input date then presumably something got lost in translation; to be honest I'm not sure whether the 12011 date would cast successfully to a string, so this is a belt'n'braces approach.   It's a bit tricky writing this utility without some test data!

This query would identify all the non-valid dates:

```
 select h.id, dump(h.bid_close_date)
 from mytable h 
 where h.bid_close_date is not null
 and is_a_date(h.bid_close_date) != 'good date';
```

Comment: +1 Assuming this actually works (I don't have test data either) I like this much better than my idea of parsing the string returned by `dump`.

Comment: In keeping with the general way many functions work, one may want to return null, if `p_date` is null. For this particular use, swallowing the null and reporting it as a good date makes sense.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance - in this case I think the most sensible option is to filter the query, so we only bother with rows where the date column is populated.

Comment: a later question is somewhat related to this same issue: behavior of Oracle in regards to corrupted (invalid) contents of a DATE column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455152/trying-to-export-a-oracle-via-pl-sql-gives-a-date-of-0000-00-00 ... but getting back to the question that was asked here... what SQL query can we write that will "validate" the contents of a DATE column, and return only the rows where the DATE column value is corrupted (i.e. invalid according to the Oracle spec for stored contents of DATE)

Answer (score 4):

Without adding a function, a simple predicate

```
TO_CHAR(date_col,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') = '000000000000'
```

appears to be satisfactory to identify corrupted values stored in an Oracle DATE column. The addition of a function appears to be unnecessary. Checking for corrupted dates should be able to be done in a SQL SELECT statement, and not require a user to have CREATE FUNCTION privilege on the database.

Comment: i wish there was a better answer to the question I asked.  A simple condition that can be used in the WHERE clause of a query, that will cause Oracle to look through all rows in a table, and validate the contents of an Oracle DATE column... and evaluate to TRUE when the contents are invalid. This answer has the simplest predicate that I could come up with. Is it reliable? Maybe there's a better way to do this. Maybe this answer can be improved. (I'm not sure why this nearly six year old answer received a downvote today),

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a method that can be implemented as a check constraint, probably through checking that the date is in the range of legal values.

However, ask yourself also whether it is valid to have a date of 1066-10-14? It is a legal value, but you probably do not have invoices printed on that day, for example. So you might like to roll the invalid date check into a larger issue of what you really consider to be valid in the context of your application.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question I asked, which was about the best method to identify existing corruption in an Oracle database DATE column.

Comment: Indeed not -- it's advice on how to choose a methodology, and on wider considerations of data validity.

Answer (score 0):

I had an `SQL Error: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"`.

So to identify the rows that had a bad date I did the following.

```
declare
    cursor mydates is select table_pk, your_date_col from table;
    c_date table.your_date_col%type;
    c_pk table.table_pk%type;
    testrow table.your_date_col%type;
begin
    open mydates;
    loop
    begin
        fetch mydates into c_pk, c_date;
        exit when mydates%notfound;
        testrow := TO_TIMESTAMP(c_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
    exception when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('bad file: ' || c_pk);
    end;
    end loop;
    close mydates;
end;
```

So all I did was create a cursor, loop through the elements and tested each one and display the identifier so I could easily find the bad rows.