# Oracle SQL: failing to convert number to char

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, number-formatting, to-char

I have a table `SOME_TABLE` with a field `SOME_NUMBER` of type number. If I try to convert this field to char, I'm getting an error in some cases.

This select

```
select  id, 
        SOME_NUMBER,
        to_char(SOME_NUMBER,'fm999999990D999999999999','nls_numeric_characters=''.,''') tochar,
        dump(SOME_NUMBER)
from SOME_TABLE 
where id in (
19876,
19886,
19857,
19792,
19810
);
```

will result in

```
+-------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
|  ID   |  SOME_NUMBER  |         TOCHAR          |     DUMP(SOME_NUMBER)      |
+-------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| 19792 | 0,00000013147 | 0.00000013147           | Typ=2 Len=4: 189,14,15,71  |
| 19810 | 0,0000001387  | ####################### | Typ=2 Len=3: 189,15,244    |
| 19857 | 0,00000011896 | ####################### | Typ=2 Len=4: 189,13,246,61 |
| 19876 | 0,00000012962 | 0.00000012962           | Typ=2 Len=4: 189,13,97,21  |
| 19886 | 0,00000011896 | ####################### | Typ=2 Len=4: 189,13,246,61 |
+-------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Furthermore, I've noticed that internal representation for erroneous examples is different from the one I can get with a "direct" select:

```
select 0.0000001387,dump(0.0000001387) dump from dual union all
select SOME_NUMBER,dump(SOME_NUMBER)from SOME_TABLE where id in (19810);
```

returns

```
+--------------+-------------------------+
| 0.0000001387 |          DUMP           |
+--------------+-------------------------+
| 0,0000001387 | Typ=2 Len=3: 189,14,88  |
| 0,0000001387 | Typ=2 Len=3: 189,15,244 |
+--------------+-------------------------+
```

and this is true **only** and **always** for the records that give me error, so this must be related with the issue.

Is this a bug in how Oracle manages number fields? Or this is an acceptable/correct/possible situation? How could I fix this? If I try to `to_char` the field without any format string the connection drops down... it cannot be normal. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Looks like you have corrupt data, unfortunately. If you don't know how or why it was corrupted you can't really trust it - you don't know if the original number was actually 0.0000001387 or something completely different. Do you know how this data was loaded? You can get corruption with OCI calls, and `imp` sometimes used to cause this kind of thing. [This has come up before here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14322493/266304), and the advice to involve Oracle Support probably applies here too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TO_char returning slash value after converting a number to String](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14273113/266304).

Comment: Tomorrow morning I'll check how data is loaded, it's a complex process. But does this discrepancy mean that my data is corrupted for sure?

Comment: I'd say so, yes. If you can figure out exactly where and how it's being corrupted (i.e. a specific bug in your load process) it's feasible you could work out what the original value was and correct it, but that seems like a long shot. Bear in mind that even the values that do convert may not actually be correct - they may just have corrupted to an internal value what happens to be a real number; or you could have some corrupted and some OK. There isn't really any way to tell. Sorry. Good luck...

Comment: Make sure the endian formats are the same. Please refer to [Database Backup and Recovery User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmxplat.htm#BRADV05432).

Comment: Unfortunately, invalid data may get into the DB in different ways - not necessarily through OCI calls. There has been some discussion of such issues on OTN -  if I remember correctly, one of the issues was that `add_months` doesn't check that the resulting year is less than `9999` and the db gladly stores the return from the function, resulting in corrupt date values. (Or, if the addition results in overflow, the year cycles back to "low" years and you get valid but incorrect date values.)

Comment: For example: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3902729?start=0&tstart=0 and https://community.oracle.com/message/13713358#13713358