# TO_CHAR(number) Function returns ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

Query:
`Select To_Number(qty) From my_table Where Id=12345;`
Output:
`ORA-01722: invalid number

01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"`

Query: `Select qty From my_table Where Id=12345;`
Output: `0.00080`

Query:
`Select To_Number(0.00080) From Dual;`
Output:
`0.00080` (no error)

This is a odd situation I am facing in Oracle. Can anybody suggest why it happens? The column `qty` is `NUMBER` type. Hence it is very hard to imagine that it contains invalid number, but it happened.
I want to clarify that it happened for the specific value in the column although we have thousands of records in the same column.
Added more: The same error appears if I use `TO_CHAR(qty)` function. The `qty` column is `NUMBER` type not `VARCHAR2`. In fact we are using `SUM(qty)` function which showed error. Hence I went for a dissection and found this row being the culprit.

Comment: what is the format of "qty" in my_table ?

Comment: It might be that there is a line break or something appended to your `qty` like `0.00080\r\n`. You should take a look at the hex dump of `qty` to make sure.

Comment: Why are you calling `to_number` on a number anyway? (And why does the title have `to_char`?). Is it really a number column though -seems odd for you client to show it with a trailing zero by default. And if it is actually a `varchar2`, what are your NLS settings, particular your decimal and group separators?

Comment: why a negative vote? I can edit the question and clarify as and when required.  
@BWS and @Alex Poole -  it is a `NUMBER` type and using `to_number` is part of my investigation, not a real query.

Comment: No idea who downvoted. What you're saying is happening doesn't immediately make any sense; maybe adding the table definition and some sample data would prevent people assuming you're giving incorrect info (e.g. number vs. varchar2). Anyway, what does `to_char(qty, '999999.99999') give you for that row - does that still have the trailing zero? I'm wondering if you have corrupt data, from an OCI program or an import. `dump()` should have shown you something interesting though in that case.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that `qty` is defined as a `varchar2` in `my_table`-- otherwise, there would be no purpose served by calling `to_number`.  If that assumption is correct, I'll wager that there is some other row in the table where `qty` has non-numeric data in it.

SQL is a set-based language so Oracle (or any other database) is perfectly free to evaluate things in whatever order it sees fit.  That means that Oracle is perfectly free to evaluate the `to_number(qty)` expression before applying the `id=12345` predicate.  If Oracle happens to encounter a row where the `qty` value cannot be converted to a number, it will throw an error.

It is also possible that there is some non-numeric data in the particular row where `id = 12345` that happens not to be displaying (control characters for example).  You can check that by running the query

```
SELECT dump(qty, 1016) 
  FROM my_table
 WHERE id = 12345
```

(if you want decimal rather than hexadecimal, use 1010 as the second parameter to `dump`) and checking to see whether there is anything unexpected in the data.

Comment: I tried your query. It shows nothing. How is this possible Oracle shows error for some other value in `qty` column not this one which I posted. If it is, can you please suggest me a way to find out the invalid value. Remaining answers I have added to the main question.

Comment: @ramesh - What does "it shows nothing" mean?  Are you saying that the `dump` query returns no data, indicating that there is no row with `id = 12345`?  Or so you mean something else?

Comment: Dump Query returns no data. So, what should I understand.

Comment: @ramesh - Can you post a cut-and-paste from SQL*Plus showing what happens when you run the query `select dump(qty,1016), qty from my_table where id = 12345`?  If the query is returning no data, that implies that there is no matching row.

Comment: you are correct. There is no matching row for the given id. I hope the row is deleted after today's reprocessing. I will check if the same problem persists for any other value and come back.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see you could get the results you've shown, given that `qty` really is a `number` field, is if it holds corrupt data (which is why there has been scepticism about that assumption). I'm also assuming your client is formatting the value with a leading zero, but is not forcing the trailing zero, which wouldn't normally appear; you can of course force it with `to_char(.0008, '0.00000')`, but you don't appear to be doing that; still, the leading zero makes me wonder.

Anyway, to demonstrate corruption you can force an invalid value into the field via PL/SQL - don't try this with real data or a table you care about:

```
create table t42(qty number);

table T42 created.

declare
  n number;
begin
  dbms_stats.convert_raw_value('bf0901', n);
  insert into t42 (qty) values (n);
end;
/

anonymous block completed

select qty from t42;

       QTY
----------
    .00080 

select to_number(qty) from t42;

Error starting at line : 12 in command -
select to_number(qty) from t42
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
```

Note the plain query shows the number as expected - though with a trailing zero, and no leading zero - and running it through `to_number()` throws ORA-01722. Apart from the leading  zero, that is what you've shown.

It also fails with `to_char()`, as in your question title:

```
select to_char(qty) from t42;

Error starting at line : 13 in command -
select to_char(qty) from t42
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

... which makes sense; your `to_number()` is doing an implicit conversion, so it's really `to_number(to_char(qty))`, and it's the implicit `to_char()` that actually generates the error, I think.

Your comments suggest you have a process that is loading and removing data. It would be interesting to see exactly what that is doing, and if it could be introducing corruption. This sort of effect can be achieved through OCI as the database will trust that the data it's passed is valid, as it does in the PL/SQL example above. There are bug reports suggesting `imp` can also cause corruption. So the details of your load process might be important, as might the exact database version and platform.

Comment: The trailing zero was causing the problem. It was not the single record, some more records were also there. And there is no such formatting the client is supposed to do. The bad values were removed after doing reprocessing for the whole acct twice. Hope I won't get the same problem. Thanks for your time and valuable suggestions.

Comment: `bf0901` Is this a hexadecimal number?
From the log files I traced, it was inserting something like '5.8E-4'. not sure how trailing zero appeared there.

Comment: @ramesh - it isn't a hex number, it's three hex bytes. If you have Oracle support access, see note 1031902.6 about how numbers are stored. The first byte (0xbf, or 191) is the exponent, and the remaining bytes are the mantissa. If you dump 0.0008 you get `bf,09`. Adding the third byte corrupts it and adds the trailing zero.

Comment: @ramesh - `dump(0.00058)` is `191,6,81`. Not sure how your load process could get from that to `191,bf,01`, but there are other values that can get the same output, such as `bf,08,65`, `bf,0a,9d`, so it could be more complicated than that. But bear in mind that a number corrupted in this way is not necessarily *invalid*, so until you find out how the corruption is occurring, you might need to consider all this data suspect?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the nearly same problem. And I found the mysterious number behaved differently from the normal number after `dump()`. For example, assuming my qty=500 (datatype: number(30,2)) , then:

```
select dump(qty) from my_table where Id=12345;

Typ=2 Len=3: 194,6,1

select dump(500.00) from dual;

Typ=2 Len=2: 194,6
```

If we know how number datatype be stored (if not, plz visit http://translate.google.com/translate?langpair=zh-CN%7Cen&hl=zh-CN&ie=UTF8&u=http%3A//www.eygle.com/archives/2005/12/how_oracle_stor.html ) , we can find that there is a tailing zero (the last extra "1" in `Typ=2 Len=3: 194,6,1`) in the mysterious number.

So I made a trick to eliminate the tailing zero, and it works for the problem.

```
select dump(trunc(qty+0.001,2)) from my_table where Id=12345;

Typ=2 Len=2: 194,6
```

Hope someone to explain the deep mechanism.

Comment: This is also just fighting the symptoms, not the cause, as you acknowledge. Since dump looks wrong this appears to be corruption (see my answer), which makes that value suspect even if you can force it back to a valid number. Valid may not be the same as correct.

Comment: Yes, you gave a valuable advice. However, there is something I don't really understand in your answer. What's the meaning of `dbms_stats.convert_raw_value('bf0901', n)` ? I've check the oracle official website http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_stats.htm#i1035014 , but I still didn't catch it. Would you please to explain it in more details?

Comment: It's sort of the reverse of `dump(x, 1016)` here. That gives you a raw picture of the internal representation of the value. `convert_raw_value` goes the other way. If you plug a valid number's dump into that you get the same valid number back. Here I'm (ab)using it to create an *invalid* number, because crucially it doesn't validate the value against the target data type. [You can create invalid dates too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12456242/266304). Not often useful to do either... *8-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select To_Number(trim(qty)) From my_table Where Id=12345;
```

Comment: This is just fighting the symptoms and not the root cause. Just saying :)

Comment: @eisberg -- I hear ya ... but sometimes, we must play the hand we are dealt :)