# ORA 00905 missing keyword in Select statement

Tags: sql, keyword

```
try {
        st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        st3 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rs = st.executeQuery("select insp_no,ro_code, inspectiondate from keroseneheader where ro_code='" + cust_code + "' and status='NO' and inspectedby='" + em.ro_code + "'");

        if (rs.next()) 
        {
          session.setAttribute("insp_no", rs.getString("insp_no"));
          out.print(rs.getString("insp_no") + "#" + rs.getString("inspectiondate"));
        } 
        else
        {
          rs3 = st3.executeQuery("select * from keroseneheader where ro_code='" + cust_code + "' and inspectiondate>to_date('" + inspectdate + "','dd-mm-yyyy') and inspectedby='" + em.ro_code + "'");

          if (!rs3.next()) 
          {
            String query2 = "insert into keroseneheader(insp_no,ro_code,inspectiondate,status,inspectedby) values((select nvl(max(INSP_NO)+1,1) from keroseneheader),'" + cust_code + "',"
        + "to_date('" + inspectdate + "','dd-mm-yyyy'),'NO','" + em.ro_code + "')";
            boolean i = DbConn.insertupdatedata(query2, false);

           if (i) {
                st1 = con.createStatement();
                rs1 = st1.executeQuery("select insp_no,to_char(inspectiondate,'dd-mm-yyyy') inspectiondate from keroseneheader where ro_code=" + cust_code + " and status='NO' and inspectedby='" + em.ro_code + "'");

             if (rs1.next()) {
        session.setAttribute("insp_no", rs1.getString("insp_no"));
        out.print(rs1.getString("insp_no") + "#" + rs.getString("inspectiondate"));
                }
             }
        } 
        else {
        out.print("Invalid Date");
        }
       }
```

Comment: Put all details in question. Explain what have you done. Did you look at the error on the internet?

Comment: sorry code is not as that clear i am new to STACK OVERFLOW so dont know much about this

Comment: in ur select statement can see `em.ro_code` what is em? Also try to use parameterized query to avoid sql injection pblm

Comment: em is object of employee                                                                                    EmployeeDetails em = (EmployeeDetails) session.getAttribute("Employee");

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
st1.executeQuery("select insp_no,to_char(inspectiondate,'dd-mm-yyyy') inspectiondate from keroseneheader
```

To this

```
st1.executeQuery("select insp_no,to_char(inspectiondate,'dd-mm-yyyy') as 'inspectiondate' from keroseneheader
```

Comment: is there any error in very first st.executequery(); sql statement

Comment: @Gourav If you debug your code, Can you tell us where it hits an exception?

Comment: the is just a part of my project and in the project i have a search box when i provide inputs and try to search there comes the error MISSING KEYWORD

Comment: Also apache tomcat logs dont tell error line number or any thing else there just comes a error named missing keyword and some error lines

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00905: missing keyword

 at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)

Comment: @Gourav ok, in my experience, 99% of the "ORA-00905: missing keyword" happens when your select statement is invalid. Either you are missing a comma between your columns or you have a error when you are naming your column. The compiler is expecting a from keyword when it gets a new column instead or a bad named column.

Comment: does this means any i found this in my apache log                                                                                at org.apache.jsp.Webpages.SkoInspection.sko_jsp._jspService(sko_jsp.java:496)

Comment: The easiest way to track down this error is for you to put a break point in your code and step through your code till it hit the exception :)

Comment: can the line "to_char(inspectiondate 'dd-mm-yyyy')" cause error ORA 01722 invalid number

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273610/to-charnumber-function-returns-ora-01722-invalid-number

Comment: Didnt helped in my case                                                               but solved that error thanks every one for help