# How to insert a date "00000/00/00 00:00:00" (dump = Typ=12 Len=7: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an issue with an old application. I tried to update date field with the value `01-JAN-99` but my application crash immediately.
In fact, I saw a strange date value in the table when I get the value with oracle function `dump()`:
`Typ=12 Len=7: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1`  and after I get the value with `to_char(t$demi, 'SYYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')` **=>** `00000/00/00 00:00:00`.

```
select 
 t$demi
 ,dump (t$demi) 
 ,to_char(t$demi, 'SYYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
from 
T;
```

Result:

```
01-JAN-99   Typ=12 Len=7: 199,199,1,1,1,1,1  9999/01/01 00:00:00
01-JAN-99   Typ=12 Len=7: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 00000/00/00 00:00:00
```

How to insert or update this kind of value in a existing table?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455152/

Comment: Please post the [SQL] `UPDATE` statement that crashed. If you got an error message, then post that also. For your information, Oracle's `DATE` data-type uses 7 (seven) bytes of storage. This old Oracle 9i [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci03typ.htm#438305) contains an example along with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this post [Trying to export a Oracle via PL/SQL gives a date of 0000-00-00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455152/)

I converted the dump with  dbms_stats.convert_raw_value('01010101010101', d)
and I updated the table with the raw value

```
create table t42(dt date);

declare
    d date;
begin

    dbms_stats.convert_raw_value('01010101010101', d);
    insert into t42 (dt) values (d);
end;
/
select 
  dt,
  dump(dt), 
  to_char(dt, 'SYYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
from t42

select * from t42
```

resutlts

```
9999-01-01 00:00:00 Typ=12 Len=7: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 00000/00/00 00:00:00
```

And very strange because  the value is less than current date…
**9999 is less than 2019!!!**

```
select 
  dt,
  dump(dt), 
  to_char(dt, 'SYYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
from t42
where dt < SYSDATE ;

9999-01-01 00:00:00 Typ=12 Len=7: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 00000/00/00 00:00:00
```