# Oracle - Extract Year from date result in 0

Tags: oracle

Duplicate of [Trying to export a Oracle via PL/SQL gives a date of 0000-00-00](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12455152/266304) as mentioned by @AlexPoole

I have a table with different dates in it, however, when I try to extract year, a single row returns an incorrect result.
This incorrect result happens when I execute the following (note that TO_DATE and FROM_DATE are both of data_type DATE):

```
select 
     TO_DATE
    ,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE) as "TO_YEAR"
    ,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE) as "TO_MONTH"
    ,EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_DATE) as "TO_DAY"
    ,FROM_DATE
    ,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FROM_DATE) as "FROM_YEAR"
    ,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM FROM_DATE) as "FROM_MONTH"
    ,EXTRACT(DAY FROM FROM_DATE) as "FROM_DAY"
    ,DUMP(FROM_DATE, 1016) as FROM_DUMP
    ,to_char(FROM_DATE, 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM_STRING
from SomeTable
```

The incorrect result is (date format is YY-MM-DD):

```
TO_DATE     TO_YEAR   TO_MONTH     TO_DAY FROM_DAT  FROM_YEAR FROM_MONTH   FROM_DAY                      FROM_DUMP           FROM_STRING
-------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------  -----------------------------  --------------------
00-02-01       2000          2          1 01-02-01          0          2          1  Typ=12 Len=7: 64,64,2,1,1,1,1  00000-00-00 00:00:00
```

My question is why does FROM_YEAR return a zero and not 2001?

Comment: Can you include `dump(from_date, 1016)` in your question? And `to_char(from_date, 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`. Just in case the value is somehow corrupt.

Comment: @AlexPoole By the look of FROM_STRING it seems to be correpted.

Comment: [Yes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1619b0111698dcc1ad8997401505ded1). So probably a duplicate [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12455152/266304). If you know what it's suppose to be you can update it, but unless you have that information independently, or know how it was populated, you won't be able to work it out from the current corrupt value.

Comment: You've updated your question to include `DUMP(FROM_DATE)` in the query; but the output suggests you actually did `DUMP(FROM_DATE,1016)` (or16, same as 1016 here). The difference is whether it's showing decimal 64 (hex 40) or hex 64 (decimal 100).

Comment: Sorry, I actually did the DUMP(FROM_DATE,1016), as shown in the question now.

Answer (score 1):

A `DATE` is stored in 7-bytes using:

- century + 100
- year-of-century + 100
- month + 0
- day + 0
- hour + 1
- minute + 1
- second + 1

Looking at the output of `DUMP`, which is `Typ=12 Len=7: 64,64,2,1,1,1,1` then you have:

- Century = -36
- Year-of-century = -36
- Month = February
- Day = 1
- Hour = 0
- Minute = 0
- Year = 0

Which would make your date midnight of 1st February 3636 BC.

Unless you intended to use dates from ancient history then it would suggest that somewhere in your application some corrupted data has been stored.

However, something else appears to be going on as that is a valid date that can be stored and `TO_CHAR` should work.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( dt ) AS
SELECT DATE '-3636-02-01'FROM DUAL;

SELECT TO_CHAR( dt, 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS dt_string, 
       DUMP( dt )
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | DT_STRING | DUMP(DT) |
> | --- | --- |
> | -3636-02-01 00:00:00 | Typ=12 Len=7: 64,64,2,1,1,1,1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=26b602f98f0721dd399620b80d6f35c1)*

and the `DUMP` matches your data but the `TO_CHAR` output is valid whereas yours is zeros.

Comment: I think the question was updated to show the dump query incorrectly; the output matches what I asked for, with hex values. (And [can replicate the output in the question](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1619b0111698dcc1ad8997401505ded1) using that). So it's hex 64, which is decimal 100; giving century 0 and year 0, which is invalid/corrupt.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, if there is a typo in the question and `DUMP` should have that second parameter to output as hexadecimal then it would make sense.