# NUMBERS pretending to be NULL in Oracle Cloud Database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, null, cloud

Our Delphi Application uses the 19.18.0.0.0 Oracle client to connect to a Oracle 19c Database in the Oracle Cloud.
Since a few months whenever it inserts some special numbers into number colums the field looks like NULL to all other applications.
Selected by the application itself the number appears to be correct.
The fun begins when you do something like this with Oracle SQL Developer or any other application:

```
-- Creating test table
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    TOOL NUMBER(1),
    COL1 NUMBER(15,2)
);


-- INSERTS performed by the application
INSERT INTO TEST (TOOL, COL1) VALUES (1, NULL);
INSERT INTO TEST (TOOL, COL1) VALUES (1, 196);
INSERT INTO TEST (TOOL, COL1) VALUES (1, 197);
INSERT INTO TEST (TOOL, COL1) VALUES (1, 198);
INSERT INTO TEST (TOOL, COL1) VALUES (1, 199);
INSERT INTO TEST (TOOL, COL1) VALUES (1, 200);
COMMIT;


-- INSERTS performed by SQL Developer
INSERT INTO TEST (TOOL, COL1) VALUES (2, NULL);
INSERT INTO TEST (TOOL, COL1) VALUES (2, 196);
INSERT INTO TEST (TOOL, COL1) VALUES (2, 197);
INSERT INTO TEST (TOOL, COL1) VALUES (2, 198);
INSERT INTO TEST (TOOL, COL1) VALUES (2, 199);
INSERT INTO TEST (TOOL, COL1) VALUES (2, 200);
COMMIT;


-- SELECT performed by the application
SELECT TOOL, COL1, COL1 + 1 COL1P1, DUMP(COL1, 16) DMP FROM TEST WHERE (COL1 IS NOT NULL);

 TOOL  |  COL1  | COL1P1 | DMP
------------------------------------------------
    1  |   196  |    197 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,61
    1  |   197  |    198 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,62
    1  |   198  |    199 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,63
    1  |   199  |    200 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,64
    1  |   200  |    201 | Typ=2 Len=2: c2,3
    2  |   196  |    197 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,61
    2  |   197  |    198 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,62
    2  |   198  |    199 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,63
    2  |   199  |    200 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,64
    2  |   200  |    201 | Typ=2 Len=2: c2,3

SELECT TOOL, COL1, COL1 + 1 COL1P1, DUMP(COL1, 16) DMP FROM TEST WHERE (COL1 IS NULL);

 TOOL  |  COL1  | COL1P1 | DMP
--------------------------------
    1  |  NULL  |   NULL | NULL
    2  |  NULL  |   NULL | NULL


-- SELECT performed by SQL Developer
SELECT TOOL, COL1, COL1 + 1 COL1P1, DUMP(COL1, 16) DMP FROM TEST WHERE (COL1 IS NOT NULL);

 TOOL  |  COL1  | COL1P1 | DMP
---------------------------------------------------
    1  |  196   |    197 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,61
    1  | NULL   |    198 | Typ=2 Len=4: c2,2,61,65
    1  | NULL   |    199 | Typ=2 Len=4: c2,2,62,65
    1  | NULL   |    200 | Typ=2 Len=4: c2,2,63,65
    1  |  200   |    201 | Typ=2 Len=2: c2,3
    2  |  196   |    197 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,61
    2  |  197   |    198 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,62
    2  |  198   |    199 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,63
    2  |  199   |    200 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,64
    2  |  200   |    201 | Typ=2 Len=2: c2,3

SELECT TOOL, COL1, COL1 + 1 COL1P1, DUMP(COL1, 16) DMP FROM TEST WHERE (COL1 IS NULL);

 TOOL  |  COL1  | COL1P1 | DMP
---------------------------------------------------
    1  |  NULL  |   NULL | NULL
    2  |  NULL  |   NULL | NULL
```

SELECT TO_NUMBER(COL1) FROM TEST;  -- ORA-01722 invalid number

This is because 198 and 199 are two of the numbers that trigger the problem but 196 and 200 are not.
These are the numbers we discovered (by accident) so far: **123, 197, 198, 199, 1480000, 1490000, 1700000, 1710000**

Using the NVL function also reveals the fact, that this is not a "real" NULL:

```
SELECT TOOL, COL1, NVL(COL1, 1000) COL1NVL, DUMP(NVL(COL1, 1000), 16) DMP FROM TEST;

 TOOL  |  COL1  | COL1NVL | DMP
---------------------------------------------------
    1  |  196   |    197 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,61
    1  | NULL   |   NULL | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,61
    1  | NULL   |   NULL | Typ=2 Len=4: c2,2,62,65
    1  | NULL   |   NULL | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,64
    1  |   200  |    201 | Typ=2 Len=2: c2,3
    2  |   196  |    197 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,61
    2  |   197  |    198 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,62
    2  |   198  |    199 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,63
    2  |   199  |    200 | Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,64
    2  |   200  |    201 | Typ=2 Len=2: c2,3
```

Also tested: Oracle Clients 19.19.0.0.0 and 21.10.0.0.0
The problem does not happen with our self hosted Databases (same application and oracle client).

How can a database field even be in a state that causes these results?

I tried any thinkable combination of tools and clients to reproduce a field behaving like this but with no success.
Searching for new ideas or someone who had the same problem.
Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: There's a bug somewhere. Though can we ask that you correct your SQL? Your results show the first column as TOOL but that isn't being selected. You'd want to make sure your SQL and the results are exactly what you are using/seeing.

Comment: Thank you. Added the column to the selected fields.

Comment: What doest it show: `select dump(col1, 16) from your_tablw where <filter on broken rows>`?

Comment: Does providing an alias for the `COL1 + 1` expression change anything?

Comment: Can you identify all rows with `select tool, col1 from test where col1 is null`? Do the results change if you leave out the `col + 1` column expression?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to export a Oracle via PL/SQL gives a date of 0000-00-00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455152/trying-to-export-a-oracle-via-pl-sql-gives-a-date-of-0000-00-00)

Comment: Your application uses some way to write raw bytes into the number column. This is the same issue as in the question above regarding dates. See reproducible example in the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/XFRN-Rem

Comment: It seems that when you use arithmetics, Oracle performs these  operations on the bytes and then adjust it's representation to confirm storage rules (it stores each two digits as a separate byte)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I tested everything suggested and added the results to the original post.
My Application is quite old (Delphi 7 using OCI-Connection) but nothing changed about the way values are inserted in NUMBER-Columns when it stopped working.
It must be some update or setting to the cloud database (managed by Oracle).
So I am open to a setting or so that restores the old behavior or something I can change in my application.

Comment: @Henning as you may notice `65` (`101` in decimal) is not a valid bytes for number. Oracle separates number in the way to keep two bytes in range 2-100: it takes modulo 100 of the number, adds 1 if remainder is not zero, and stores it as the highest bytes (skipping first two bytes reserved for sign and scale). Then shifts number by 2 decimal places and does the same, appending bytes to the left. The first byte stands for sign and scale and increases every 1000. See https://dbfiddle.uk/6irs_Sr5. Bringing all together: an app does some "dirty" inserts of raw bytes (or OCI breaks the data)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, astentx!
I came, thanks to your hints, to the same conclusion but I didn't understand it in that detail as your last comment.
Now I still have to find out what changed since it last worked but I now know much better what to look for.

Comment: It appears that the Oracle Client was updated between the last time an INSERT of a "forbidden Numner" was successfull and when it became NULLish.
It was 18.5.0.0.0 and was upgraded to 19.18.0.0.0 (19.19.0.0.0 and 21.10.0.0.0 also don't work).
Yes, connecting with an 18 client to a 19 database was no problem.
Unfortunately there is no back to the old client because the newer one is needed for the new wallet which is needed for encryption.