# Getting "ORA-01482: unsupported character set" when using WHERE IN pattern

Tags: oracle

I have a table with the following structure in Oracle database:

```
CREATE TABLE PASSENGERS
(ID VARCHAR2(6),
 PASSPORTNO VARCHAR2(14));
```

I want to get the IDs of the passengers who have been registered more than once. For that I run the following query.

```
SELECT ID FROM PASSENGERS WHERE PASSPORTNO IN 
  (SELECT PASSPORTNO FROM PASSENGERS
     GROUP BY PASSPORTNO 
     HAVING COUNT(*)>1);
```

But I get "unsuported character set" error. What's the point I'm missing?

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=582240 might help you

Comment: Does these queries run properly without any error : 1. SELECT PASSPORTNO FROM PASSENGERS   2.   SELECT PASSPORTNO FROM PASSENGERS
     GROUP BY PASSPORTNO

Comment: @loki, yes, if I run these queries separately, they execute without a problem

Comment: Can you try this also : SELECT count(PASSPORTNO) FROM PASSENGERS, i feel this should give error.

Comment: nop, @loki, it runs perfectly fine

Comment: This is strange as i thought it might be [should be] data issue. How big is data in passengers table? Is it possible for you to provide it?

Comment: There are 25k+ records in the table.

Comment: This is a really weird problem.  I wonder if the data got corrupted somehow?  You may want to try to identify some individual values that cause the problem, and then look at them with the `dump` function.  Your problem may be indirectly related to a problem like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8734540/409172

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all queries related with PASSPORTNO are running fine you have at least two more things to do:

1. Run `SELECT ID FROM PASSENGERS` and check for errors, if the error cames up, then it may be releated with content stored in your table
2. Try another SQL tool to execute your queries, your client OS may be using a system enconding which the database can't understand both when processing your query of to display the returning rows.

Since both ID and PASSPORTNO are varchar fields, there's a big change to one of then have data in a enconding which oracle can't decode properly.

Comment: SELECT ID FROM PASSENGERS runs normally. And I tried it on SQL plus and got the same error

Comment: When you say the SQL runs normally, and that it errored in SQL Plus, where did it run normally?  And is the the tool that you are trying to use for your final query?

Comment: @Karl, I ran the same error-returning query on SQL Plus in Windows 7. ANd got the same error.

Comment: Yes, @ararog, you seem to be right. I deleted 90% of the records (of course in a cloned table) and tried to run the query afterwards. And guess what, it worked. So, some record(s) contain(s) an encoding which either Oracle or Windows can't decode.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly seems like a data issue. Try checking the exact data row which is causing the issue.

Use : **DML Error Logging** - http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2.php

Btw, you are doing `GROUP BY passportno` .Is that correct? (This implies multiple passports can have same passport number). I guess it should be `GROUP BY id`

Comment: I do grouop by because the same person, can have been a passenger more than once, and considering that there's no profile tracking system installed yet (I know that would be better, but it's another topic) then this is the way it should be.