# select invalid date string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a `nvarchar2` column in a database table, that stores strings which represent dates, for example '2016-12-05'.

Any way to detect rows that do not contain a valid date string, for example `'2012-19-34'`?

---

I would like to have a statements that sets any invalid date string to `null`.

Comment: By storing them as a `date` instead of a `varchar`?

Comment: Please post what you tried so far; besides, is there an index on your column? what do you mean with "the best"?: the fastest, the most readable, ...?

Comment: "the best" means "any" so far.

Comment: to add on @Siyual, how´d you easily check for the 29th of february for example? You could try to select them on by one and use a `to_date`. the ones running into an exception would be invalid. And using a `date` to beginn with would have been the best option.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734540/how-to-identify-invalid-corrupted-values-stored-in-oracle-date-columns) for a clever solution using a custom date validator.  As others have said, store dates as dates, and maybe handle the check in your app layer.

Comment: I am working with an application that already exists and I do not have permission to change the types of the columns. I have to work with what I have.

Comment: Are all your dates in the format `YYYY-mm-DD` ?

Comment: yes, they are all YYYY-mm-DD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can write a function that try to convert the string into the date:

```
create function check_date(p_date_str  in nvarchar2) return number as
v_result NUMBER(1,0);
v_date    DATE;
begin 
  v_result := 1;
  begin 
    v_date := to_date( p_date_str, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  exception  when others then 
   v_result := 0;
  end;
return v_result;  
end;
/
```

and then use it to find invalid records:

```
select * from my_table where check_date(column_with_date_as_str) = 0;
```