# Why am I seeing values of '2432-82-75 50:08:01' in Oracle DATE column?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, date, ssis, etl

As part of my job duties, I'm responsible for extracting data from our vendor's Oracle 11g database, and loading it into our SQL Server 2016 database. I've been doing this successfully with SSIS and the Attunity Oracle connectors.

Today I was informed that there was a new column added to the existing `Invoices` table on the Oracle side. There was already a DATE column called `Order Date`, which contains valid date values with zero'd times, like `2017-12-25 00:00:00`.

The new column is called `Order Date Time` and is also a DATE column. When I opened up the SSIS package and pulled up the Oracle source in my DFT, I previewed the data and found the values in `Order Date Time` to be `2432-82-75 50:08:01`. I tried converting the column with `CAST` and all the `TO_*` functions, but the conversions either failed outright, or returned a string of zeros.

```
TO_CHAR("Order Date Time", 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

yields `00000000000000`

After a bit of Googling for "Oracle date value invalid", I'm now thinking that these DATE values are actually corrupted. Am I missing anything here? Is there some sort of special Oracle-specific technique for storing time values in a DATE column that I may not be aware of?

(And yes, it does bother me quite a bit that our vendor added another DATE column instead of just using the time portion of the existing `Order Date` column.)

Comment: Something doesn't match here. You said a date column was added but then wonder why vendor did not use the time portion of existing column. That is inconsistent. But rather than wonder, did you ask someone who has actual access to the database to use the Oracle tools and verify some row samples? And perhaps verify the actual schema is what you think it is?

Comment: There was already an "Order Date" column of type DATE, where all the values have "00:00:00" as the time component. A new column, "Order Date Time", also of type DATE was then added to the table today. I don't understand why they added a new DATE column, when the existing DATE column could have been used to store the order date with time value.

Comment: I have put in a question to the Oracle dba at our vendor, but speedy responses to database issues are not their strong point. I also question the competence of the Oracle dba, for this and other facepalm-y reasons.

Comment: Oracle DATE fields contain both date and time components. There's nothing special about it - they are really timestamp fields, accurate down to an interval of 1 second. I suggest logging in to the Oracle database directly to check that the date fields contain valid values. BTW - what's the data type of the SQL Server-side field?

Comment: That does indeed sound like corrupted values. It is, indeed, possible to load such values into an Oracle database (as sad as that is). See for example https://community.oracle.com/thread/3903746?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Oracle database engine allows [inserting invalid date values](https://blog.dbvisit.com/how-to-insert-invalid-dates-into-oracle-and-how-to-replicate-this/), which leads to many problems especially when importing data to others database engines such as SQL Server.

To handle this issue, you have to implement the logic that fits your needs, as example:

- You can exclude these records from you queries by filtering on acceptable date ranges: *(WHERE date between ...)*
- You can Update records with invalid values by replacing with `NULL`
- You can use a `CASE` statement in your query to replace values with `NULL`

I faced this issue one time while importing data to SQL Server from an Oracle data source, there was unacceptable date values, i decided to update all records where date are invalid and replace with `NULL` values before starting the import process.

---

There are many links related to this issue:

- [Detecting invalid values in the DB](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3903746?start=0&tstart=0)
- [How to identify invalid (corrupted) values stored in Oracle DATE columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734540/how-to-identify-invalid-corrupted-values-stored-in-oracle-date-columns)
- [Corrupt date fields causing query failure in Oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93363/corrupt-date-fields-causing-query-failure-in-oracle)
- [Invalid Date in DATE Column SQLPlus VS SQLDeveloper](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4033662)
- [Ask Tom - date validation in oracle](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9528368000346452927)
- [Dealing with invalid dates](https://dbvisit.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ugdr/pages/10289194/Dealing+with+invalid+dates)
- [Error: Invalid date format](https://support.timextender.com/hc/en-us/articles/215011803-Error-Invalid-date-format)
- [DB Connect; Oracle DB date field data is corrupt](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/785655)